# connexion: Failed to find Flask application or factory in module

Tags: python-3.x, flask, connexion

I've started to develop a Flask based API using Flasks Blueprints. That worked like a charm.
Then I started to refactor it, to use connexion and a swagger specification.
After that, I'm not able to launch the application. I get following error message:

```
Use "FLASK_APP={module}:name to specify one.'.format(module=module.__name__)
flask.cli.NoAppException: Failed to find Flask application or factory in module "api.app". Use "FLASK_APP=api.app:name to specify one.
```

Versions used:

- Python 3.7.6
- connexion 2.7.0
- Flask 1.1.2

My structure looks like:

```
api
 |-.flaskenv
 |- init.py
 |- app.py
```

.flaskenv

```
FLASK_APP=app.py
FLASK_ENV=development
```

_*init_*.py

```
# from flask import Blueprint
# bp = Blueprint("api", __name__)
# from api import endpoints  # , errors  # noqa F401, errors, tokens
```

app.py

```
# from flask import Flask
# from api import bp as api_bp
import connexion


# app = Flask(__name__)
# app.register_blueprint(api_bp, url_prefix="/api")
app = connexion.FlaskApp(__name__, specification_dir="./")
app.add_api("swagger.yml")
```

Launch (inside my venv):

```
flask run --no-debugger
```

If I uncomment the classic Flask coding (and comment on the connexion coding), everything worked, and the endpoints are accessible.

I checked also the environment variables that are available at the time `app = connexion.FlaskApp(__name__, specification_dir="./")` is called. There are the values from `.flaskenv` available.

From my understanding, `connexion` has `Flask` bundled, and when using the class `FlaskApp`, it's creating an app like the vanilla Flask framework.

My example is the same as in the [connexion documentation](https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#running-it).

I've no idea why vanilla Flask creates the application and connexion not ...

Thanks.

mybecks

Comment: It turns out, that I was missing the following line in the `app.py`: `application = app.app`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution**

`app.py` must be extended by one line to expose a Flask class object: `application = app.app`

```
app.py

import connexion

app = connexion.App("__name__", specification_dir="./")
app.add_api("swagger.yml")
application = app.app
```